# How to use JMockit MockUp for default interface method

Tags: jmockit

Trying to apply a `MockUp` on a Java 8 default interface method, and JMockit tells me that method cannot be found. This has been tried with JMockit 1.15, 1.19, and 1.25. Here's a very simple use case:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TestTest {

    public interface MyInterface {
        default void foo(int f) {
            bar(String.valueOf(f));
        }

        void bar(String s);
    }

    public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        public void bar(String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testtest() throws Exception {
        new MockUp<MyClass>() {
            @Mock
            void foo(int i) {
                System.out.println("MOCKMOCK " + (i*2));
            }

            @Mock
            void bar(String s) {
                System.out.println("MOCK " + s);
            }
        };

        MyClass baz = new MyClass();

        baz.foo(5);
        baz.bar("Hello world");
    }

}
```

This gets me the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matching real methods not found for the following mocks:
com.example.dcsohl.TestTest$1#foo(int)
    at com.example.dcsohl.TestTest$1.<init>(TestTest.java:29)
    at com.example.dcsohl.TestTest.testtest(TestTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

How can we @Mock this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Mocked` instead of a `MockUp`, it supports default methods.

Comment: So `MockUp` simply doesn't support this at all? I don't generally use `MockUp` unless I have to, and this seemed to be a situation to warrant it--obviously, more complex than the above method... but this is a no-can-do?

Comment: Yes, currently (up to JMockit 1.25), `MockUp` does not support methods implemented in interfaces (default or static methods). In the future, support may be added.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modifying your use case to return strings instead of printing to standard out the following solution will work.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import mockit.Expectations;

public class TestTest {

    public interface MyInterface {
        default String foo(int f) {
            return bar(String.valueOf(f));
        }

        String bar(String s);
    }

    public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        public String bar(String s) {
            return s;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testtest() throws Exception {

        MyClass baz = new MyClass();

        new Expectations(MyClass.class) {{
            baz.foo(anyInt); result = "FOOMOCK";
            baz.bar(anyString); result = "BARMOCK";
        }};

        assertEquals(baz.foo(5), "FOOMOCK");
        assertEquals(baz.bar("Hello world"), "BARMOCK");
    }

}
```

There are many useful examples of how to mock out interfaces with method bodies (ie default or static methods) outlined in the examples section on the jmockit [github repository](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/blob/master/samples/java8testing/test/java8testing/InterfacesWithMethodBodiesTest.java).